# How to set Search Bar's text on Navigation Bar Title Text?

Tags: ios, swift, search, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I am getting idea of a new app. I love to find a many tricks. however, No luck for me.

The simple.

You can see swipe down the search bar from the below of the navigation bar.

Result:

```
    // iOS 13 Navigation Bar only
    self.navigationItem.title = "Search Title"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
              
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    
    let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
         
    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
          
    app.backgroundColor = .clear
    app.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    app.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.label]
    app.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.label]
    app.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
              
            
    navigationBar!.standardAppearance = app
    navigationBar!.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
```

Search Result:

```
// Search Bars
    let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    search.searchBar.delegate = self
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self as? UISearchResultsUpdating
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    search.searchBar.searchTextField.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    search.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "magnifyingglass")?.withTintColor(UIColor.systemGray), for: .search, state: .normal)
             
     self.navigationItem.searchController = search
        
    (UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]) ).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(white: 100, alpha: 0.50)]
          
     let textField = search.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField

     let glassIconView = textField.leftView as! UIImageView
     glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
     glassIconView.tintColor = UIColor.systemGray

     let clearButton = textField.value(forKey: "clearButton") as! UIButton
     clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
     clearButton.tintColor = UIColor.systemGray
```

Now, I am tried to look for the trick code to set the search bar's text will appear navigation bar when you have searched it. (Yes, It is a very familiar to Safari style).

I don't like Search Bar title text stayed on the small of the search bars, so move to a large title look better.

Let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method of `UISearchBarDelegate`.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624294-searchbarsearchbuttonclicked)

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.navigationItem.title = searchBar.text ?? "Search Title"
}
```

If you need to update the title as the user types in search bar, use `updateSearchResults` of `UISearchResultsUpdating`. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchresultsupdating/1618658-updatesearchresults)

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.navigationItem.title = searchController.searchBar.text ?? "Search Title"
}
```